# Spring Boot Tutorial doesn't work with multi project gradle setup

Tags: spring-boot

i get a strange behaviour (at least for me :D) when I switch from the gradle file located in https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ to a multi project gradle file setup.

build.gradle in root directory

```
//Applied to all projects.
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'


    group = 'de.test.platform'
    version = '0.1'
}

subprojects {

    //Currently all subprojects are also java projects. If this changes we
    //need to move it into the corresponding projects
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    idea {
        module {
            downloadSources = true
            downloadJavadoc = false
        }
    }
}

idea {
    project {
        jdkName = '1.8'
        languageLevel = '1.8'
    }
}
```

build.gradle in sub directory frontend (thus sub project called :frontend)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'crowdio-frontend'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

when I run gradle bootRun and navigate to http://localhost:8080/greeting as in the tutorial i get a infinite loop error. If i change the template from greeting.html to hello.html and return hello instead of greeting in the controller greeting() action i get an 404 Error.

The template is stored in project_root/frontend/src/main/resources/templates/greeting.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that for whatever Reason spring boot can decide on thymeleaf with the exact structure of the gradle build file like in the tutorial. However if you switch to a multi project setup you need to add

```
compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4")
```

as a dependency.